# Android url Concatenation

Tags: android, url

I'm asking about the right way to concatenate a url with values !
here my example **"http://10.0.2.2/myFolder/page.php?value1=!!&value2=!!,+value1,+value2"**
I hope you will understand what I'm saying cause I'm  new to Android and thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is related to Android. What is your `page.php` expecting that it doesn't get? If there are errors/stacktraces, post them. Also, please post the relevant code of `page.php` and from your Android app where you concatenate the URL.

Comment: my page.php works fine, but my problem is that i want to pass variable of value 1 and values 2 (the values changes) so i want to use a dynamic url !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jamal, Are you trying to concatenate the String: "http://10.0.2.2/myFolder/page.php?value1=!!&value2=!!,+value1,+value2"   ?

If so, Please try the follwing:

```
String uri = "http://" + address + "/myFolder/page.php?" + value1 + "=" + value2;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thx a lot this works fine bbut there is a little prob when i pass this url 'String uri = "http://10.0.2.2/folder/save.php?valeur1=" +a +"valeur2="+b;'  i get the result valeur1=avaleur2b ?!

Comment: it seems like valeur1 get the variable of a the string valeur2 and its variable ? am i missing something

Comment: Is there no URL aware way of doing this that prevents double slashes and the likes?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is almost correct, but you should be URL encoding the keys and values:

```
String uri = "http://" + address + "/myFolder/page.php?" + URLEncoder.encode(value1) + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value2);
```

Comment: +1 Ian is right, make sure you encode your values because you might get crashes or malformed calls to your web service..

Comment: Thank you All for helping me ;) i found the problem i forgot to add the & between valeur1 et valeur2 // **"http://10.0.2.2/myFolder/save.php?valeur1="+a +"&valeur2="+b;**

Answer (score 1):

you can use [stringbuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and append the as many lines and values you want to add

like wise in your case

```
StringBuilder sb = ("http://").append(address).append("/myfolder/page.php?").append(value1).append("=").append(value2);
```

and then use the following

```
sb.toString();
```

hope this might helps you.I have used this in my one of the projects